# Deriving the rocket equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

Recently I decided to brush on the those parts of classical mechanics that always gave me trouble. One of those parts was the [rocket equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) so I figured that I would try to derive the appropriate equations from scratch. Evidently I ran into trouble somewhere, so I am hoping that someone can point out my errors and steer me in the right direction. Anyway here goes ...

Suppose a rocket expels exhaust behind it with constant velocity (relative to the rocket) $\mathbf{u}$. Fix an inertial reference frame and consider the rocket + exhaust system. If $m_R$ denotes the instantaneous mass of the rocket, then the momentum of the rocket can be written as $m_R\mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the instantaneous velocity of the rocket. The momentum of the exhaust ought to be given by the integral:

$$\int (\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u})\frac{\mathrm{d}m_E}{\mathrm{d}t} \; \mathrm{d}t$$

where $m_E$ denotes the instantaneous mass of the exhaust. Combining these expressions for the momentum, we arrive at the total momentum for the system:

$$\mathbf{p} = m_R\mathbf{v} + \int (\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u})\frac{\mathrm{d}m_E}{\mathrm{d}t} \; \mathrm{d}t$$

Now according to the 2nd Law of Motion, the force acting on the rocket + exhaust system is obtained from $\mathbf{p}$ by taking time derivatives. In other words:

$$\mathbf{F} = \dot{\mathbf{p}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}m_R}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathbf{v}+m_R\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t}+(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u})\frac{\mathrm{d}m_E}{\mathrm{d}t} = m_R\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} - \frac{\mathrm{d}m_R}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathbf{u}$$

This expression superficially matches the ones in my college mechanics books, but there is one big difference. In this expression $\mathbf{F}$ is the total force acting on the rocket + exhaust system, while in my texts this $\mathbf{F}$ is just the force acting on the rocket alone.

So based on this I have made some fundamental error somewhere in my argument. As I asked before, if anyone could help me identify this error and correct it, I would be much obliged.

Comment: "_the force acting on the rocket alone_" -- I'd express as $\mathbf{ F }_R := m_R \, \mathrm{d/d}t( \mathbf{ v } ) = \mathbf{ F }_R^{external} + \mathbf{ u } \, \mathrm{d/d}t( m_R )$; while "_the total force acting on the rocket + exhaust system_" -- I'd express as $\mathbf{ F }^{external}$, where it is perhaps usually assumed that it is irrelevant which forces act on the exhaust matter once it has been expelled, so perhaps $\mathbf{ F }^{external} := \mathbf{ F }_R^{external}$. I conclude that your texts are sloppily worded ...

Comment: Why is the momentum of the exhaust given by that integral instead of simply $m_E (v+u)$, where $m_E$ is the mass of gas already expelled at time $t$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an error on your part.  The force on the rocket must equal the time rate of change of the rocket momentum *only* so either the texts are misleading or plain wrong.

There is no external force acting on the rocket / propellent *system* so the center of mass of the rocket / propellent system, as a whole, does not change.

Thus:

$m_R \cdot d\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u} \cdot dm_R$

or

$dv = -u \dfrac{dm_R}{m_R} $

which leads to

$\Delta v = u [\ln(m_{R,i}) -  \ln(m_{R,f})] = u  \ln\dfrac{m_{R,i}}{m_{R,f}}$

Comment: Right so this leads to the correct equation for the velocity in the absence of external forces. But when I try my approach in say, the presence of a gravitational field, I get incorrect results. For example, if I want to find the velocity in this case, I get $(m_R+m_E)g = m_R\dot{v}-u\dot{m}_R$ and I can solve for $v$ from here. However, Kleppner and Kolenkow say that I should have $m_Rg = m_R\dot{v} - u\dot{m}_R$ and that I should solve for $v$ from there. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Ah I think I identified the source of my error. In the case where there are no external forces acting on the system, the derivation goes through just fine. But when I consider external forces acting on the system, the expression I have for the momentum of the exhaust is incorrect. An additional term is needed to correct for whatever momentum is gained/lost due to the external force acting on the exhaust. Do I have this right?

Comment: Yes, an external force on a system will change its momentum according to the formula you stated in you question. However the propulsion due to expelled exhaust gasses will apply an internal force on the rocket/propellant system, so no change of momentum of the system.